# Passing model-object to a viewcontroller through a viewcontroller that doesn't need it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

There have been many similar questions to this about passing data from a view-controller to an adjacent view-controller.

However, I haven't been able to find any solutions to situations where a model object is used and initialized in a view-controller, then there is a segue to another view-controller that doesn't make use of the model object, and then another segue needs to happen to a view-controller that does need to make use of the model-object.  How do I hide the model-object from the middle view-controller while exposing it to the last view-controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [singleton instance](http://jason.agostoni.net/2012/01/22/ios-best-practices-singletons/) of the model class in the app delegate, then reference it via AppDelegate.h in only the VCs that actually need to access the model. [Another reference](http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-10%E2%80%93Singletons-and-the-AppDelegate).

Comment: Same response to jlukanta's response: I would like to avoid globally accessible references like a singleton pattern. I was thinking about one solution was to have some navigation-like controller class that could contain references to all models and, upon a transition to a new view-controller, would pass models to the view-controllers that need it - more of a layered approach to model reference passing.

Comment: @corporate_fun: I think you just answered your own question, but a separate controller class that only holds model references would be pretty much the same as putting those singleton references in the AppDelegate. You'd still have to instantiate the class & model references, and would still have to import that class' .h to the VCs that need it. Plus side, you'd encapsulate the models references in a separate place so it doesn't bloat the AppDelegate. As far as the approach, that would still be basically the same solution. In fact, you just described jlukanta's Option #1...

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to get a callback every time there is a transition between view-controllers so that the object can be notified when a new view-controller is showing up so that the view-controller can be instantiated with the models instead of the other way around of having the view-controllers access the object to get the models.

Answer (score 0):

You have several alternatives.

1. Stick the object into an object that both the middle-man and the destination share.
2. Make the object global. Possibly using singleton pattern or AppDelegate.

Comment: I would like to avoid globally accessible references like a singleton pattern.  I was thinking about one solution was to have some navigation-like controller class that could contain references to all models and, upon a transition to a new view-controller, would pass models to the view-controllers that need it - more of a layered approach to model reference passing.

The first approach is also not desirable because it still doesn't restrict access to the models